# Are concrete Riemann surfaces Riemann domains over $\mathbb C$?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

While reading about Riemann surfaces I stumbled upon the following two definitions. A Riemann surface of a complete analytic function is an example of both definitions while Abstract Riemann Surface is a generalisation of both definitions. So it seems like every (non singular, concrete) Riemann surface can be considered as Riemann domain over $\mathbb C$ or maybe vice versa. But I am unable figure it out. I am also curious about the historical origins of these definitions.

**Riemann surface:**

A subset $S \subseteq \mathbb C^2$ is called a (non-singular, concrete) Riemann surface if for each point $s \in S$, there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $s$ and a holomorphic function $F$ on $U$ with non-zero gradient at $s$ such that $S \cap U$ is the zero set of $F$.

**Riemann domain over $\mathbb C$:**

A topological space (Hausdorff and connected) $G$ is called a Riemann domain over $\mathbb C$ if there exists a local homeomorphism map $\pi:G \to \mathbb C$.

Comment: Hint: use the implicit function theorem

Comment: Implicit function theorem is local theorem, how can I use it to construct global map $\pi$?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the definition. I thought we require there to be locally a homeomorphism between neighbourhoods (which is precisely what implicit function theorem would guarantee)

Comment: What are the sources of these definitions?

Comment: Riemann surface definition is from Riemann surface notes by C. Teleman available online and Riemann domain definition is from SCV book by Narasimman/Fritsche and Grauert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are theorems of Gunning and Narasimhan (Gunning, R. C., and Raghavan Narasimhan. "Immersion of open Riemann surfaces." Mathematische Annalen 174.2 (1967): 103-108.) and a theorem of Narasimhan (Narasimhan, R. "Imbedding of open Riemann surfaces", Göttingen Nachrichten, No. 7 (1960), pp. 159-165; also see American Journal of Mathematics Vol. 82, No. 4 (Oct., 1960), pp. 917-934) that almost(!) demonstrate an equivalence.

The first paper proves (quoting from the paper):

**Theorem**: Any (connected) open Riemann surface $X$ admits a holomorphic 
immersion into the complex plane; that is, there is a holomorphic mapping $F:X\to\mathbb{C}$ which is a local homeomorphism.

In other words, given any surface $S$ as in the original post above there is a holomorphic mapping $F:S\to\mathbb{C}$ exhibiting it as a $G$ as in the original post.

In the second paper it is proved that (quoting from the third paper!) "any open Riemann surface has a non-singular imbedding in $\mathbb{C}^3$".

In general, going from $\mathbb{C}^3$ to $\mathbb{C}^2$ *will* introduce some singularities. So going back all the way to $\mathbb{C}^2$ *may* not be possible.

A possible reason for such a obstruction is given below, but it is *not* a counter-example until proven!

For example, a smooth compact Riemann surface of any genus has an embedding in $\mathbb{CP}^3$. However, a *general* smooth compact Riemann surface of genus 6 does not have an embedding in $\mathbb{CP}^2$.

One can produce curves of degree 6 in $\mathbb{CP}^2$ with 4 nodes whose desingularisations are compact Riemann surfaces of genus 6. The 4 nodes will (in general) *not* lie on a line, so one cannot get an open Riemann surface of the type above by removing a $\mathbb{CP}^1$. Note, however, that this is not a *proof* that it cannot be done since there are more holomorphic functions on an open Riemann surfaces than those obtained by restrictions of meromorphic algebraic functions on the compact one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does first theorem also hold for  abstract Riemann surface (i.e. 1 dimensional complex manifold)?

Comment: @MayureshL Yes. Any open connected 1 dimensional complex manifold.

Comment: Ohh! Means studying open connected 1 dimensional complex manifold (i.e. open connected Abstract Riemann surface) is same as studying Riemann domain over $\mathbb C$

Comment: The reverse direction question seems to be at a research level so I have asked it on MO as [a new question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314137/embedding-open-connected-riemann-surfaces-in-mathbbc2). Hope that is OK with @MayureshL.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my last comment. Riemann domain over $\mathbb C$ implies concrete Riemann surface is Research problem. But I think Riemann doamin over $\mathbb C$ implies abstract Riemann surface is always true (we can give complex structure on Riemann domain to make it complex manifold).

Comment: I understood your comment. Indeed, all abstract open Riemann surfaces are of type $G$. The question of whether a $G$-type is also expressible as an $S$-type is the Bell-Narasimhan Conjecture according to [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/314149/124862) I got on Math Overflow!

Comment: Thanks! I also have written my thoughts on your question on Math Overflow.